# VueRouter - Load pages only when needed

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-router

I am developing a CRM with dozens of pages and using VueRouter for navigation. At the moment, the loading of the routes I am doing as follows (2 options):

Option 1:

```
const BrokerContactsDetails = () => import('src/pages/ContactsDetails.vue');

(...)

  {
    path: 'contacts/details/:id',
    name: 'ContactsDetails',
    components: {
      default: BrokerContactsDetails
    },
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      roles: ['All'],
    }
  }
(...)
```

Option 2:

```
    {
    name: 'ContactsDetails',
    path: 'contacts/details/:id', component: () => import('src/pages/ContactsDetails.vue'),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      roles: ['All'],
    }
  }
(...)
```

However, when I use the webpack-bundle-analyzer and enter "/", I realize that the page for this route is already loaded.

Printscreen: http://imageshack.com/a/img922/5/0vjBpw.png

Any tip to lazy load the page only when the route is accessed?

Thanks

Comment: can you show basic structure of ContactsDetails?

Comment: Its a simple page with another component which contains lots of components (is a huge page).